# Sunspot/Solr search by complete address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I m bit new with rails and introducing first time Sunspot/Solr solar search.

my requirement is something like this.

I have columns in my DB

1. city
2. state
3. country
4. building no
5. zip code

but a user is entering anything like(" San 140 Mason Street San Francisco, CA 94102 United States")  in above fields in a text box. i have to populate the relevant result.

in modal

searchable do

```
text :city
text :state
text :country
text :building_name
```

end

in controller....

@search =CompanyDetail.search do

```
  fulltext params[:job] do
    fields(:city, :state,:country,:building_name)
  end

end
@company_details=@search.results
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please put your code here

Comment: thanks for replying ... added the code there